# Some questions being closed to quick.

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

There seems to be a fair number of questions be closed, that are not that subjective. Too much hastiness is damagaing. Some questions are being closed before it's being understood w

Like this.

[What are some sites that provide science fiction stories in audio form (for free)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/754/what-are-some-sites-that-provide-science-fiction-stories-in-audio-form-for-free)

Comment: I think this question would be better suited if you are asking why a specific or category of questions was closed, rather than in it's current form.

Comment: Sounds like a cromulent question to me. On the main meta site there is a discussion about if it is better to just close or if it is better to work with people. On the biggest sites moderators are just closing-- there are too many bad questions. Here, on a beta!, this is inappropriate. The mass closures are just make it feel like a dangerous place to post questions.

Comment: If someone's editing the title, the missing 'o' would be nice too :)

Comment: Well, that meta question was posted too quickly, but it wasn't closed too quickly. As usual, the community can close questions; if you object to a closure of a specific question, comment or post on Meta.